# How to get table name from IDbCommandInterceptor in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interceptor

I have an `Interceptor`.

```
public class EfQueryLogsInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command,
         DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
         //string tableName = ???
    }
}
```

I want to get the table name in the `ReaderExecuted` method.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MetadataWorkspace` of the context has a lot of useful information:

```
public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command,
                           DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
{
    // It's taken form https://romiller.com/2014/04/08/ef6-1-mapping-between-types-tables/
    var context = interceptionContext.ObjectContexts.First();
    var metadata = context.MetadataWorkspace;
    var entityTypes = metadata.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace);
    foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
    {
        var entitySet = metadata
                        .GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.CSpace)
                        .Single()
                        .EntitySets
                        .Single(s => s.ElementType.Name == entityType.Name);
        var mapping = metadata.GetItems<EntityContainerMapping>(DataSpace.CSSpace)
                              .Single()
                              .EntitySetMappings
                              .Single(s => s.EntitySet == entitySet);
        var table = mapping
                    .EntityTypeMappings.Single()
                    .Fragments.Single()
                    .StoreEntitySet;
        var tableName = (string)table.MetadataProperties["Table"].Value ?? table.Name;

        //TODO: Use tableName
    }
}
```